# Accepting dragged files on a Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a simple application that handles marketing information. What I did was to call

```
NSInteger result  = [openPanel runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil types:fileTypes];
```

When the user clicks on the `File->Open` menu. Now I was asked to add drag and drop capabilities to the app so the user can drag a file to it instead on having to go to the menu or pressing command+o to open a file.

Before you tell me to **go read the documentation** I already check Apple's [Intro to drag and drop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html) and other documents. Still I can't figure out what to do.

I'm an old Unix C programmer that need to copy with this and some of the assumptions at the Apple's document don't make sense to me.

In short, what do I need to add to my app to:

1. Enable drag and drop
2. Handle that dragged file

As a note, I should handle only one file at a time.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you need to implement the NSDraggingDestination protocol, which I presume you've read already. You can implement it in either a specific view or the entire window -- it sounds like you are accepting application-level file drags so you probably want the entire window to accept the drag. Regardless, once you get it working you'll see how to customize it further.

Subclass NSWindow. The first step is to specify what kinds of drags you are interested in.

Tell your custom window that it's interested in filenames:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];
}
```

Tell OS X what kind of cursor to display:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender {
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}
```

Do the drag:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSArray *filenames = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];

    if (1 == filenames.count)
        if ([[NSApp delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(application:openFile:)])
            return [[NSApp delegate] application:NSApp openFile:[filenames lastObject]];

    return NO;
}
```

This is the bare minimum to get it working.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. When I place `[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];` to `awakeFromNib` I get an exception and and: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyAppAppDelegate registerForDraggedTypes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100141330'

Comment: Oh, also adding `[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];` gives me a warning: Method -registerForDraggedTypes not found

Comment: You need to call that method on the window or view that's accepting drags. I prefer to call it from the window itself, in `awakeFromNib` in my NSWindow subclass.

Comment: I am doing that. The `MyAppAppDeletage` is the code that handles the only window for the application.

Comment: Do I need to change anything on the project settings? Anywhere? I feel like I am missing something...

Comment: I've edited the above code. If you just copy and paste it into a fresh subclass of NSWindow it will work. Make sure you are specifying the correct custom class for your window in your NIB file.

Comment: Thank you but I still get an exception on awakeFromNib on `[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]]`. And I am still seeing the warning. I am missing something.

Comment: OK, got it. I changed `self` to `[self window]` and it's working. Now, how do I set the focus on the window once it is dragged? Now I can load the contents of the file but when I release the mouse over the window the file "goes back" to the Finder and the window doesn't get focus (although it loads the file).

Comment: When the file is opened successfully, are you returning `YES` in the application:openFile:` method of your application delegate?

Comment: I have `- (IBAction)OpenFile:(id)sender` that is called when the button open is pressed and then `- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender `. Those two feed a function that is the one handling the actual file opening, I am passing the filename to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6021/discussion-between-francis-mcgrew-and-mr-aleph)